# QGIS Atlas generation - Export atlas as images - only JPEG, want PNG

Tags: qgis, png, atlas

I can't find an option to choose image format while exporting Atlas, choices are Export atlas as images / as SVG / as PDF

[image: screenshot of choices]

The dialog that opens has no options and it always exports as not so good jpeg.

OS X 10.10, QGIS 2.6 & 2.8.1

Comment: Could be a bug? I use QGIS 2.6 for Windows and have the option to save as PNG using **Export as Images**. Hopefully others can advise. Could an alternative be to save it as a PDF and then copy the image from there and re-save as a PNG in an image editor?

Comment: I can do **Export as image...** from Composer dropdown (or toolbar button) and then I can choose png or any other format, so it's not so big problem, more of an convenience issue.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! You can always send a [request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) to the development team.

Comment: Ok, posted a bug report: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12435